# Probability density function of Continuous random variable X.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X be a continuous random variable with the probability density function

$ f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \frac{x+1}{2}, \quad -1 < x < 1  \\ 0,  \quad \text{otherwise} \end{array} \right. $

Then $  P(\frac{1}{4}< X^2 <\frac{1}{2})$ is

I integrated $f(x)$ from $\frac{1}{4} $ to $ \frac{1}{2}$ and got $\frac{11}{64}$

But I don't know whether my answer is correct or not.

if my approach is wrong then what is the correct method to do this question?

Comment: The integral you computed is for $P(\frac{1}{4} < X < \frac{1}{2})$. Can you think about how to modify your work for $P(\frac{1}{4} < X^2 < \frac{1}{2})$?

Comment: Edit your questions instead of [reposting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3791441/321264).

Comment: Your approach is incorrect as $f(x)$ is the probability distribution for $X$ and not for $X^2$. There is however a way to write the probability you are interested in in terms of $X$ instead of in terms of $X^2$. Can you see how you can rewrite it such that it is in terms of $X$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given
$$  P(\frac{1}{4}< X^2 <\frac{1}{2})$$
$$  P(\frac{1}{2}< X <\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$$

$$  P(\frac{1}{2}< X <\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) = \int_{\frac{1}{2}} ^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}  \frac{x+1}{2} = 0.166 $$